# How to tar specific file extension files?

Tags: include, tar

I have file types *.cpp,*.h,*.o,*.so,*.a
I need to tar only *.cpp and *.h files.
as of now i am using --exclude=*.{o,so,a} unwanted files to tar. 
but if i have many unwanted extensions the exclude list comes very big. 
what is the command to include specific file extensions to tar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 find -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" | xargs tar -czvf build.tar.gz
```

Comment: i must do it recursively i cant give each file name, its tidius

Comment: @Ram modified to based on your comment